# convert timespan to readable text

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert TimeSpan object to text that can be read like a sentence.
e.g.

```
TimeSpan(2, 1, 0, 0) --> "2 days and an hour"

TimeSpan(1, 2, 1, 0) --> "A day, 2 hours and a minute"
```

Some more samples for conversion are in the 'TestCases' object under 'TimeSpanPrettyFormatterTests' class.

Is there any better way to do it than the one i suggested here?

Thanks

```
using System;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Client.Tests
{

   [TestFixture]
   public class TimeSpanPrettyFormatterTests
   {
    [UsedImplicitly]
    static object[] TestCases =
        {
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0), string.Empty },

            new object[] { new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0), "A day" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0, 0), "2 days" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0), "An hour" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(1, 1, 0, 0), "A day and an hour" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(2, 1, 0, 0), "2 days and an hour" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0), "2 hours" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(1, 2, 0, 0), "A day and 2 hours" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(2, 2, 0, 0), "2 days and 2 hours" },

            new object[] { new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0), "A minute" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(1, 0, 1, 0), "A day and a minute" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(2, 0, 1, 0), "2 days and a minute" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(0, 1, 1, 0), "An hour and a minute" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1, 0), "A day, an hour and a minute" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(2, 1, 1, 0), "2 days, an hour and a minute" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(0, 2, 1, 0), "2 hours and a minute" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(1, 2, 1, 0), "A day, 2 hours and a minute" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(2, 2, 1, 0), "2 days, 2 hours and a minute" },

            new object[] { new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2, 0), "2 minutes" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(1, 0, 2, 0), "A day and 2 minutes" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(2, 0, 2, 0), "2 days and 2 minutes" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(0, 1, 2, 0), "An hour and 2 minutes" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(1, 1, 2, 0), "A day, an hour and 2 minutes" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(2, 1, 2, 0), "2 days, an hour and 2 minutes" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(0, 2, 2, 0), "2 hours and 2 minutes" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(1, 2, 2, 0), "A day, 2 hours and 2 minutes" },
            new object[] { new TimeSpan(2, 2, 2, 0), "2 days, 2 hours and 2 minutes" }
        };

        [Test, TestCaseSource("TestCases")]
        public void ParseTimespan_ShouldReturn(TimeSpan timeSpan, string expectedResult)
        {
            string formatedText = timeSpan.ToPrettyFormat();
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, formatedText);
        }
    }

    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static string UppercaseFirst(this string s)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
        }
    }

    public static class TimeSpanExtensions
    {
        public static bool HasDays(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            return timeSpan.Days != 0;
        }

        public static bool HasMinutes(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            return timeSpan.Minutes != 0;
        }

        public static bool HasHours(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            return timeSpan.Hours != 0;
        }

        public static string ToPrettyFormat(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            string result;

            if (timeSpan.HasDays())
            {
                if (timeSpan.HasHours())
                {
                    if (timeSpan.HasMinutes())
                    {
                        result = GetDays(timeSpan) + ", " + GetHours(timeSpan) + " and " + GetMinutes(timeSpan);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = GetDays(timeSpan) + " and " + GetHours(timeSpan);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    result = GetDays(timeSpan) + (timeSpan.HasMinutes() ? " and " + GetMinutes(timeSpan) : string.Empty);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (timeSpan.HasHours())
                {
                    result = GetHours(timeSpan) + (timeSpan.HasMinutes() ? " and " + GetMinutes(timeSpan) : string.Empty);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = GetMinutes(timeSpan);
                }
            }
            return result.UppercaseFirst();
        }

        private static string GetMinutes(TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            if (timeSpan.Minutes == 0) return string.Empty;
            if (timeSpan.Minutes == 1) return "a minute";
            return timeSpan.Minutes + " minutes";
        }

        private static string GetHours(TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            if (timeSpan.Hours == 0) return string.Empty;
            if (timeSpan.Hours == 1) return "an hour";
            return timeSpan.Hours + " hours";
        }

        private static string GetDays(TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            if (timeSpan.Days == 0) return string.Empty;
            if (timeSpan.Days == 1) return "a day";
            return timeSpan.Days + " days";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicate with http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25009/format-a-timespan-with-years

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ToPrettyFormat` method can definitely be improved. Instead writing the conditional statement for all possible permutations of `HasDays`, `HasHours` and `HasMinutes` it's better to step back and define rules for resulting string:

- string may consist of 3 parts (days, hours and minutes)
- if there is 0 or one non-empty part - it is a final result
- if there are 2 non-empty parts - there should be "and" between them
- if there are 3 non-empty parts - first 2 should be separated by comma + "and" before last part. Note that we can actually generalize last two rules for N parts (months, weeks, etc) - instead of "3" we can say *combine first N-1 parts with comma and add last one with "and"*

As a result you can get a bit simplified code:

```
public static string ToPrettyFormat(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    var dayParts = new[] { GetDays(timeSpan), GetHours(timeSpan), GetMinutes(timeSpan) }
        .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        .ToArray();

    var numberOfParts = dayParts.Length;

    string result;
    if (numberOfParts < 2)
        result = dayParts.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
    else
        result = string.Join(", ", dayParts, 0, numberOfParts - 1) + " and " + dayParts[numberOfParts - 1];

    return result.UppercaseFirst();
}
```